# Pausing a Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using following code to create and execute thread i need to stop it but cant see thread .Sleep

any ideas how can i stop for a while the execution there?

```
var t = new Thread(() =>
{
try
   {
           //Line 1
             Pause here
           //Line 2
             Pause here
           //Line 3
   }
   catch (Exception ca)
   {
          MessageBox.Show(ca.Message);
   }
   });
   t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
   t.Start();
```

Comment: Any idea why Thread.Sleep can't be used?

Comment: Note: `MessageBox.Show` won't work in the thread, you have invoke that in the main thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean that you want to instruct the Thread to wait at a particular checkpoint until some other Thread tells it to continue, one good option is to use [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

```
  t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
```

I'll work from the assumption that this was intentional.  Couple of things you *have* to do to meet the STA contract.  You *have* to pump a message loop, call Application.Run().  And you *cannot* pause, that blocks any marshaled call and makes deadlock very likely.

Not a problem, when you pump a message loop you're always in an idle 'pause' state.  Make code run just as you'd normally do in a GUI main thread.  Application.ExitThread ends the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use the static method `Thread.Sleep(int)` inside your delegate

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx

Suspends the current thread for a specified time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()` method?

Answer (score 0):

add this line at the top of your code:

```
using System.Threading;
```

then you can see `Thread.Sleep()`